# Iptable forward configuration

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I have OpenVPN and PPTP installed on a VPS. I'm having a few questions that I can't seem to get a firm answer on.

I want to install OpenVPN on 1.1.1.1 (eth0, public IP address) and PPTP on 1.1.1.2 (eth0:1, public IP address). I was able to achieve this with SNAT. However, from all the tutorials I've been reading it recommends forwarding ppp+ to eth0 and vice versa and the same situation for the tun interface.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
```

My setup is CentOS, dedicated server.

For some reason I'm assuming iptables will route all traffic from eth0 to tun0 and stop at that.

My question is,

1) Will these forward rules conflict with each other?
2) Will I need to forward the ppp+ to eth0:1 instead to avoid confliction? Is it even possible? I haven't figured out a way yet. 
3) Is iptables smart enough to route traffic that is specific to tun and ppp through these rules?

Answer (score 4):

First let's try to clean up the situation a bit as you seem to confuse certain things about how packet filtering and routing work together.

- `iptables` (actually, Netfilter — that's the name of the in-kernel stack; `iptables` is just the name of a user-space binary to operate the Netfilter rule sets) does not route anything; routing is done by the routing stack (controlled using the `ip` user-space binary), and Netfilter is only able to affect the routing by rules installed in the `PREROUTING` chain (where DNAT could be done).
- The chain "FORWARD" (of the "filter" table) is being traversed by all the packets coming *through* the host, that is, not originated on it (those are going via the "OUTPUT" chain) and not destined to it (those are going through the "INPUT" chain).

  Hence yes, if packet forwarding is enabled on the host (and thus the host works as a router) the policy of the chain "FORWARD" and any rules in it do affect the *flow* of certain packets, but *not* the routing decisions.
- Each of the principal three chains — `INPUT`, `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` has the so-called "default policy", which might be either `ALLOW` (the default) or `DROP`. The latter just discards any packet entering the chain.  The default policy applies to a packet if the packet wasn't handled by the rules installed in the chain.
- It's customary for a typical "border gateway" (a host interfacing a LAN to the Internet) to have such a setup so that everything is blocked by default — including forwarding packets via Netfilter, even though it's enabled for the IP stack itself, — and then specific rules inserted to explicitly enable specific kinds of traffic.  That is, these tutorials usually advise to set the default policies for `INPUT` and `FORWARD` to `DROP` and then explicitly enable certain kinds of traffic using rules.
- Which network interface to use for sending packets is decided by the routing stack (Netfilter, again, has no say in this process) based on the routing table(s) and interface metrics, if a specific host/network is reachable via more than one route.

  If you run `ip route` on your router host, you'll see a set of rules looking like this

  ```
  10.8.10.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
  ```

  where the "via" address designates the next router and "dev" lists the interface to send the packet on to reach that router.

Now let's get back to your situation.

- You only need to place specific rules in the `FORWARD` chain if its policy is `DROP`, otherwise it will "just work".
- If you `DROP` packets in your `FORWARD` chain by default, then you need to explicitly allow passing packets between VPN interfaces and the interface facing Internet, that is, between `ppp+` *and back* and between `tun+` and back.  If you need the clients of different VPN networks to be able to talk with each other you will also need to enable forwarding of packets between respective interfaces (in both directions).
- Note that you don't *have to* refer to interfaces when writing rules for the `FORWARD` chain (or any other, actually), — you can just use network addresses (for the `-s` and `-d` command-line options of `iptables`).

  Hence, if your VPNs provide two private networks, A and B, you can insert a pair of rules like

  ```
  iptables -A FORWARD -s A -d B -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -s B -d A -j ACCEPT
  ```

  Also, since VPNs usually provide private networks, as do LANs, I tend to just insert something like

  ```
  iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168/24 -d 10/8 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -s 10/8 -d 192.168/24 -j ACCEPT
  ```

  to express the idea "everyone is able to talk to everyone else on my private networks" (if you want to also cover the less used `172.16/12` private range, there will be `3x3=9` rules needed, obviously).

*Update:* note that you do not necessarily have to enable forwarding of packets between VPN interfaces and the interface connected to the Internet: the former are virtual and only carry packets in private networks *inside* the VPN-provided tunnels; packets that *provide* these tunnels flow to/from VPN processes running on the host and do not traverse the `FORWARD` chain. So if you only need your VPN clients to talk with your LAN or between themselves, you only need to enable forwarding of packets between the VPN (and LAN, if present) interfaces.